# array_key_exists not working properly

Tags: php

I want to check if a particular index in my array exists or not. I'm using this code:

```
 if(array_key_exists('resource_id', $_POST['resource_id']) == false)
 {
      $_POST['resource_id'] = 'undefined'; 
 }
```

the `$_POST['resource_id']` is a field of my array that I pass into an ajax request from js code. Now the problem's that in some case I can't pass the resource_id field and I need to valorize it as `undefined` inside my condition as  the code above. 
The `array_key_exists` return me this error:

> Message: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think your second parameter $_POST['resource_id'] is returning null,try to print it and see what it is returning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i well understand, 'resource_id' doesnt exist all the time
So what you want to test is if it exist in $_POST array :

```
if(array_key_exists('resource_id', $_POST) == false)
{
     $_POST['resource_id'] = 'undefined'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work if you did the array_key_exists on just $_POST, but for simplicity I'd recommend:

```
if(!isset($_POST['resource_id']){
    $_POST['resource_id'] = 'undefined';
}
```

Comment: Actually it can be an array.

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter to `array_key_exists` should be just the array, so in your case, it would be

```
if(array_key_exists('resource_id', $_POST) == false)
{
     $_POST['resource_id'] = 'undefined'; 
}
```